# Find size for container with x rows, y columns defined maxWidth and defined maxHeight

Tags: javascript, html, math

I am trying to find the best dimmensions for a container.

I have to work with these values:

- Window max width
- Window max height
- Items to fit in each column
- Items to fit in each row

Each item needs to be a square, and the container has to fit the items exactly. I also need the container to be as big as possible, without it getting larger than max width in x direction, and max height in y direction.

My current code, (Which does not really work), looks like this:

```
[dWidth, dHeight] = [window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight];
// Adjust sizes, for the tiles

var tiles = (width + height) / 2;

dSize = (dWidth / tiles) > (dHeight / tiles) ?
  (dHeight / tiles) : (dWidth / tiles);

dSize |= 0,

dWidth = width * dSize,
dHeight = height * dSize,
```

- `dWidth` is the width for the container I want to create
- `dHeight` is the height for the container I want to create
- `width` is the amount of columns I have
- `height` is the amount of rows I have
- `dSize` is the height and width of every item.

No need to worry about the weird `dWidth` assignment, it's temporary.

No need to worry about `dSize |= 0`, I will not get negative values.

No need to worry about the snippet ending with a comma, the next lines is just assigning the `dWidth` and `dHeight` to a canvas.

Answer (score 1):

The number of squares you can fit horizontally is `dWidth/width` and the number you can fit vertically is `dHeight/height`.  Therefore you can work out the maximum number that will fit like so:

`var dSize = Math.min(dWidth/width, dHeight/height);`

If you need an absolute value, go ahead and use `Math.floor` on the result.

Comment: Testing this for now